# Can I install an old version of my sound drivers on a new version of Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, sound

My audio output socket is damaged, but Ubuntu's older version was kind enough to let me plug earphones and use them anyway (windows wasn't as 'nice').

I didn't update for a while since I feared that would change. But I finally gave in and updated my release. Now my earphones won't output any sound any more which is frustrating.

Is there a way I can replace my current sound drivers with old ones? Or at least other ones that might do the same trick?

I don't really remember which release I used. It was the newest one about two-three years ago.

Comment: I would recommend you to create a LiveUSB for the "newest one about two-three years ago" to find out which one works for you. Otherwise it's hard to know it's a bug on Ubuntu or not.

Comment: @P.-H. Lin
Hey, thanks for the reply. It's definitely my output that is damaged. Purely mechanical damage. It just seems that the damage wasn't so severe so Ubuntu drivers still managed to work around it.

Could you be more specific with doing a LiveUSB thing? What is that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know which version works for you is to create a LiveUSB. Things you will need to do:

1. Download an old Ubuntu images (ISO file) from http://releases.ubuntu.com/
   Go for something like ubuntu-12.04-desktop-amd64.iso
2. Create a LiveUSB for it, insert a USB, search "Startup Disk" in your dash, and select the ISO file for it, detailed instructions could be found here: [How to create a bootable USB stick
   on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)
3. Once you have it ready, [boot the system from the USB](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) that you just created, and select "Try Ubuntu without installation".

I would recommend you to give Precise 12.04 a try (12.04 or 12.04.1, not 12.04.2 ~ 12.04.5). Since it's released in 2012, and it runs on [3.2 LTS kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.A12.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support), which means that it will be maintained till 2017.

For other [releases in-between 12.04 and 14.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.Ubuntu_Kernel_Support), you still could give them a try, but note that some of them are not supported anymore.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but does that not mean I'll have to use an old version of Ubuntu? I can just re-install an old version. I was hoping there's a way to use old drivers on a new version.

Comment: I think the driver for audio is in the kernel, you can install old kernel (3.2) and give it a try, hold shift key on boot to boot in other kernels.